# Add encoding parameter to logging.basicConfig

Tags: python, logging

How do I add an `encoding` parameter to [`logging.basicConfig`](https://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig)?

I have found [this bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue11593) that states that this is now possible for Python 3.3. I need this for Python 2.7 and the bug report says to use a custom [`logging.FileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.FileHandler) object, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It will be easier to avoid using `basicConfig()` in your case - just create the handler and add it programmatically (ensuring that the code runs just once), e.g.:

```
root_logger= logging.getLogger()
root_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) # or whatever
handler = logging.FileHandler('test.log', 'w', 'utf-8') # or whatever
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(name)s %(message)s')) # or whatever
root_logger.addHandler(handler)
```

That's more or less what `basicConfig()` does.

**Update:** In Python 3.9 and later versions, `basicConfig()` has `encoding` and `errors` keyword parameters available.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(name)s %(message)s'))` ?

Answer (score 22):

You can pass a list of specific file handlers:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(handlers=[logging.FileHandler(filename="./log_records.txt", 
                                                 encoding='utf-8', mode='a+')],
                    format="%(asctime)s %(name)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s", 
                    datefmt="%F %A %T", 
                    level=logging.INFO)
```

and it works pretty well (python version == Python 3.6.8 :: Anaconda, Inc.)

Answer (score 11):

Vinay's response was very helpful, but to get it working I had to tweak the syntax:

```
root_logger= logging.getLogger()
root_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) # or whatever
handler = logging.FileHandler('test.log', 'w', 'utf-8') # or whatever
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)s %(message)s') # or whatever
handler.setFormatter(formatter) # Pass handler as a parameter, not assign
root_logger.addHandler(handler)
```