# How to encode log file?

Tags: python, logging, python-3.x, encoding

My code:

```
logging.warning('FASE VALIDACIÓN TITULOS DE COLUMNAS DE DATOS NO SUPERADA. compruebe los nombres de los títulos de las columnas en datos.csv)')
```

Output in .log file:

```
WARNING:root:FASE VALIDACI�N TITULOS DE COLUMNAS DE DATOS NO SUPERADA. compruebe los nombres de los t�tulos de las columnas en datos.csv)
```

Then I tried this:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename=nombreFicheroLog, encoding="utf-8", level=logging.DEBUG)
```

But it does not work. Then I tried this one:

```
logging.warning(u'FASE VALIDACIÓN TITULOS DE COLUMNAS DE DATOS NO SUPERADA. compruebe los nombres de los títulos de las columnas en datos.csv)')
```

But the output is the same.

How I can encode the .log file to support UTF-8?

P.S. I'm using Python3.

Comment: Adding a `u` to a string in Python 3 doesn't do anything.  Strings are unicode per default in Python 3 anyway.

Comment: How do you look at the output .log file when you see your strange `�` character?  Have you looked at it in a hex dump of that .log file?  (Maybe it's just the log file viewer who is not displaying the utf 8 correctly.)

Comment: @Alfe, I'm looking at the output file with Pycharm IDE: Settings: File Encodings -> IDE Encoding -> 'UTF-8', 'Autodetect UTF' is checked; Proyect Encoding -> <System Default>

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`basicConfig` does not take an `encoding` argument, but in Python 3.3 you can do this instead:

```
logging.basicConfig(handlers=[logging.FileHandler(nombreFicheroLog, 'w', 'utf-8')], 
                    level=logging.DEBUG)
```

For older Pythons, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10706547/222914).

Comment: Thank you @JanneKarila, that works fine.  But now, I need to read how it works in [Advanced Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/logging.html#logging-advanced-tutorial); I don't like to use things that I don't know how to use.  ;-)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know the FileHandler has to be in array. Here, have my ↑.

Answer (score 0):

Since Python3.9 you can set `encoding` in `logging.basicConfig`:
https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig

For previous versions you also can configure a stream with 'utf-8' encoding, without explicitly using handler:

```
logging.basicConfig(stream=open(nombreFicheroLog, 'w', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

source: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/81292 (https://bugs.python.org/issue37111)