# FileHandler encoding producing exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, encoding, python-logging

I have a current project that uses the python logging library to output logs to a file. I am using the logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler. For some odd reason, when I leave the encoding parameter default (like so)
`file_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(log_filename, maxBytes=500000, backupCount=3)` I get a traceback as follows (redacted):

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "%PYTHONPATH%\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 71, in emit
    if self.shouldRollover(record):
  File "%PYTHONPATH%\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 185, in shouldRollover
    self.stream = self._open()
  File "%PYTHONPATH%\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1037, in _open
    return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
LookupError: unknown encoding: ascii
Call stack:
  File "%PATHTO%\MYCLASS.py", line 705, in __del__
    self.MyMethod()
  File "%PATHTO%\MYCLASS.py", line 1738, in disconnect
    self._log_message('Enter disconnect method.', logging.INFO)
  File "%PATHTO%\MYCLASS.py", line 1096, in _log_message
    self._logger.info(message)
Message: 'Enter MyMethod.'
Arguments: ()
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "%PYTHONPATH%\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 71, in emit
    if self.shouldRollover(record):
  File "%PYTHONPATH%\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 185, in shouldRollover
    self.stream = self._open()
  File "%PYTHONPATH%\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1037, in _open
    return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
LookupError: unknown encoding: ascii
Call stack:
  File "%PATHTO%\MYCLASS.py", line 705, in __del__
    self.disconnect()
  File "%PATHTO%\MYCLASS.py", line 1760, in disconnect
    self._log_message('Exit disconnect method successfully.', logging.INFO)
  File "%PATHTO%\MYCLASS.py", line 1096, in _log_message
    self._logger.info(message)
Message: 'Exit MyMethod successfully.'
Arguments: ()
```

But it seems if I explicitly define encoding='UTF-8' or even encoding='ASCII' the traceback is never produced. I've even called with 'ascii' in lowercase: `file_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(log_filename, maxBytes=500000, backupCount=3, encoding='ascii')` and no exceptions. What's the deal? I suspect the problem has something to do with the RotatingFileHandler encoding defaulting to None type and me being on Windows. But opening files normally without an encoding has never produced errors.

I know my 'problem' already has a solution. Just explicitly define whatever encoding I want. But I'd like to understand this behaviour better.

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, but I've found this happening during interpreter shutdown if `__del__` methods call the logger. There appears to be a race condition between the log teardown and the `__del__` methods on interpreter exit. (Part of the general "`__del__` is not guaranteed to run" principle, I guess.) Not Windows-specific, as this happens for me on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

you can get your answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706547/add-encoding-parameter-to-logging-basicconfig). When it happened to me, it turns out I was using a single backslash instead of a double