# How to encode text in Choregraphe NAO

Tags: python-2.7, nao-robot, choregraphe

[Encoded text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk9kH.png) 
I want to read list from file but its getting all coded and .encode doesn't really work

```
    import json,sys
    with open('your_file.txt') as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()

    self.logger.info(lines)
    self.tts.say(lines[1])
```

Comment: Can you share your_file.txt file so that I can take a look at it?

Comment: 0
Разработка поведения робота NAO для использования в процессе обучения
1
Что такое антропоморфный робот?
2
Кибер - педагог Ева
На данный момент в России существует кибер-педагог Ева, который был создан в 2016  IT-лицеем КФУ. 
3
Робот НАО
4
Конструктор «Хореограф»
5
Функционал робота НАО
Робот обладает большим внутренним инструментарием который позволяет создавать и программировать большое количество уникальных функций
6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file is saved with UTF-8 encoding, this should work:

```
with open('text.txt', encoding = 'utf-8', mode = 'r') as my_file:
```

If this doesn't work, your text file's encoding is not UTF-8. Write your file's encoding in place of `utf-8`. [How to determine the encoding of text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220/how-to-determine-the-encoding-of-text)

Or if you share your input file as is, I can figure that out for you.

Comment: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: Have you imported with `from io import open`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o

Comment: it still getting coded info u0420\u0430\u0437\u0440\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0442\u043a\u0430 \u043f\u043e\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f

Comment: Ok, that's good. You should print it like this: `yourStringVariableNameHere=u"\u0420\u0430\u0437\u0440\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0442\u043a\u0430 \u043f\u043e\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f"` and `print(u"{}".format(yourStringVariableNameHere))`. The output of my code is "Разработка поведения"

Comment: in choregraphe print function dont work so i have to use logger.info and i getting TypeError: in method 'info', argument 1 of type 'std::string const &'

Comment: Can you try the method proposed here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711471/3124100 PS: I'd just log it as unicode, and decode it when I'll use it.