# Python's string.format() and Unicode

Tags: python, unicode

I'm having a problem with Python's `string.format()` and passing Unicode strings to it.  This is similar to [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545263/utf-8-in-python-logging-how), except that in my case the test code explodes on the print, not on the `logging.info()` call. Passing the same Unicode string object to a logging handler works fine.

This fails equally well with the older `%` formatting as well as `string.format()`. Just to make sure it was the string object that is the problem, and not print interacting badly with my terminal, I tried assigning the formatted string to a variable before printing.

```
def unicode_test():
    byte_string = '\xc3\xb4'
    unicode_string = unicode(byte_string, "utf-8")
    print "unicode object type: {}".format(type(unicode_string))
    output_string = "printed unicode object: {}".format(unicode_string)
    print output_string

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unicode_test()
```

The string object seems to assume it's getting ASCII.

```
% python -V
Python 2.7.2

% python ./unicodetest.py
unicode object type: <type 'unicode'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./unicodetest.py", line 10, in <module>
    unicode_test()
  File "./unicodetest.py", line 6, in unicode_test
    output_string = "printed unicode object: {}".format(unicode_string)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf4' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Trying to cast `output_string` as Unicode doesn't make any difference.

> output_string = u"printed unicode object: {}".format(unicode_string)

Am I missing something here? The documentation for the string object seems pretty clear that this should work as I'm attempting to use it.

Comment: Using your code as above but prepending `printed unicode object` with `u` works for me (Python 2.6.5 and 2.7). Is the error you are getting when you do that the same one as listed above?

Comment: Wait... you're encoding a unicode byte stream which is supposed to represent an already encoded unicode stream?  What character should print above for `'\xc3\xb4'`: `ô` or `Ã´`?

Comment: It should be ô.  The encoding example was copied pretty much verbatim from the referenced older post about the logging module.

Comment: And yes, I get the same error when I prepend the string with `u`.

Comment: What is your default encoding?  try: `import sys; print sys.getdefaultencoding()`

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because when I try the above code on my machine, it works just fine.  My default encoding is utf-8.

Comment: @EudisDuran Which means you're most likely using Ubuntu that does this sort of trickery. Anything other than 'ascii' will lead you to false assumptions that mixing bytes and text makes any sense.

Comment: @lqc I'm on MacOS X actually.  I set my default encoding to utf-8 in the system site.py hook

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No this should not work (can you cite the part of the documentation that says so ?), but it should work if the formatting pattern is unicode (or with the old formatting which 'promotes' the pattern to unicode instead of trying to 'demote' arguments).

```
>>> x = "\xc3\xb4".decode('utf-8')
>>> x
u'\xf4'
>>> x + 'a'
u'\xf4a'
>>> 'a' + x
u'a\xf4'
>>> 'a %s' % x
u'a \xf4'
>>> 'a {}'.format(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec 
  can't encode character u'\xf4' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> u'a {}'.format(x)
u'a \xf4'
>>> print u"Foo bar {}".format(x)
Foo bar ô
```

Edit: The `print` line may not work for you if the unicode string can't be encoded using your console's encoding. For example, on my Windows console:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'cp852'
>>> u'\xf4'.encode('cp852')
'\x93'
```

On a UNIX console this may related to your locale settings. It will also fail if you redirect output (like when using `|` in shell). Most of this issues have been fixed in Python 3.

Comment: @mpounsett: Well, as you can see in the console session I posted, `u'Whatever {}'.format(u'\xf4')` works, so you may want to recheck your code. Is the error exactly the same? Does it happen in the same line or is it more like: http://ideone.com/Z3y5Kg ?

Comment: Hrm.. I had thought the error was exactly the same, but on a recheck I see it actually migrates to the print statement.