# Encoding Problems when running an app in docker (Python, Java, Ruby, ...) with Ubuntu Containers (ascii, utf-8)

Tags: java, python, ruby, docker, locale

On my own PC the application runs nice, but when it gets deployed into docker, it fails because of invalid characters.

I am using the `ubuntu:latest` container and `python3`, `java` and `ruby`.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to set the **locale** correct.

This is the minimal correct Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt update && apt -y install locales && locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
```

The usual docker images don't specify a locales. You see it if you bash into it and execute `locale`:

```
sudo docker exec -i -t yowsup3 bash
```

Sources:

- http://jaredmarkell.com/docker-and-locales/
- https://github.com/docker-library/python/issues/13

Comment: In some cases running `locale-gen` and setting `LC_ALL` is enough.

Comment: 1. You can omit the ":latest" as it is the [default tag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-an-image-from-docker-hub)
2. The ubuntu container is missing the locales package which includes the `locale-gen` command, so the second line should be:
`RUN apt update && apt -y install locales`

Comment: I've added your correction. Thx

Comment: Or set all env vars in one line: `ENV LANG='en_US.UTF-8' LANGUAGE='en_US:en' LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'`

Answer (score 4):

I tried the above solution and found that the locale-gen command is not available inside my docker.

so add this line above the RUN command or add it in.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales && locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

this will now work.

and second ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8 is enough to set most of the variable but it left with the two vacant so that's why we need all 3 to set.

Comment: This really solved the issue!

Answer (score 1):

docker ubuntu 18.04 image use Unicode fix

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV LANG=C.UTF-8
```

add this env variable to docker file

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM centos:7 

ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Adding the above one line in docker file worked for me