# Jenkins file encoding for npm

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm

I am getting the specials replacement character in the console output of my Jenkins jobs that use npm.

```
      ���  2 warnings
```

I've tried the usual fixes such as setting the default encoding to UTF8, using the Ansii color plugin and setting my browser encoding to UTF8, but I am still getting the black diamond with the '?' in it.  Not a huge deal, but it is annoying - anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that one of the Jenkins Slave servers was had its encoding set to ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF8.  Even though the Master server was set to UTF8 and the job itself was setting the LOCALE to UTF8 it was being overridden by the Slave configuration.

Comment: I had the same problem because i was running jenkins in docker. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931668/encoding-problems-when-running-an-app-in-docker-python-java-ruby-with-u/27931669#27931669

Answer (score 0):

Next to supplying the following "Environment variables" to a Jenkins node configuration:

- LANG=en_US.UTF-8
- LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

I additionally needed to add the JVM Option "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" to the node's Java setup. (how to do that depends on the "Launch method" of the node)