# Django UnicodeEncodeError when logging sql with unicode from BinaryField

Tags: python, django, unicode

Django 1.11, Python 3.5, Windows OS

I have a Django model with a BinaryField. When I save an instance of the model to the database Django prints out an error message like this:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 216: character maps to <undefined>
```

The last line of the traceback indicates that the error is occurring in `django.db.backends.utils.py` -- I've added a comment to the offending line:

```
class CursorDebugWrapper(CursorWrapper):

    # XXX callproc isn't instrumented at this time.

    def execute(self, sql, params=None):
        start = time()
        try:
            return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
        finally:
            stop = time()
            duration = stop - start
            sql = self.db.ops.last_executed_query(self.cursor, sql, params)
            self.db.queries_log.append({
                'sql': sql,
                'time': "%.3f" % duration,
            })
            ##### Error is reported from the logger.debug statement
            logger.debug(
                '(%.3f) %s; args=%s', duration, sql, params,
                extra={'duration': duration, 'sql': sql, 'params': params}
            )
```

So I think what's happening is that when Django tries to print the SQL insert statement it hits a non-printable Unicode character and throws an error. I don't want to disable Django debug logging while I'm developing (it is disabled in production, of course).  Any way to work around this issue?

Comment: I set the handler for the `django` logger to INFO and that prevents the error. But then I'm not able to see debug level logs.

Comment: Have you tried using `'%r'` instead of `'%s'` for items that might be problematic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the encoding of the log handler to utf-8 seems to work. If there's a better way please advise.

```
LOGGING = {
    # other config omitted
    'handlers': {
        'django-debug': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(LOCAL_LOGGING_PATH,'django-debug.log'),
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'encoding':'utf8', # this fixes UnicodeEncodeError
        }
    }
}
```

---

Things I tried that didn't work. These all still produce UnicodeEncodeError:

- Add `from __future__ import unicode_literals` at the top of settings.py
- Add the Byte Order Mark (BOM) character \ufeff to the formatter as suggested by the [python 3 logging cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#inserting-a-bom-into-messages-sent-to-a-sysloghandler)
- Use %r instead of %s in the log formatter
- Use the python unicode string on the formatter `'format': u'%(asctime)-s %(levelname)s [%(name)s]: %(message)s',` and then `logging._defaultFormatter = logging.Formatter(u"%(message)s")` as suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22320208/8480899)