# python Log info with UTF-8 encode

Tags: python, logging, operating-system

I use request.get function to get search result on the internet. I was trying to record it in the log. But I don't know why it doesn't show with encoded string

```
    export=request.get(url="https://trains.ctrip.com/pages/booking/getTransferList",params=data,headers=headers)
logging.basicConfig(filename=rb"C:\Study\Other\Self-study\Code\newfile.log", 
                    format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', 
                    filemode='wb')
handler = logging.FileHandler(rb"C:\Study\Other\Self-study\Code\newfile.log", 'wb') 
logger=logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logging.info(export.content)
```

Here is part of the output

```
"transferList":[{"departStation":"\xe4\xb8\x8a\xe6\xb5\xb7\xe8\x99\xb9\xe6\xa1\xa5","arriveStation":"\xe5\x
```

But when I use json to write it

```
f=open("C:\Study\Other\Self-study\Code\export.json","wb")
f.write(export.content)
f.close
```

I got correct output

```
"transferList":[{"departStation":"上海虹桥","arriveStation":"南昌西",
```

I know the export is a response class, and export.content is binary, I tried both binary write or write with UTF_8 encode, but both got the same wrong output. Is there anyway I can got correct log in this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 In Python logging, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545263/utf-8-in-python-logging-how)

Answer (score 1):

As described [in this answer by Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57004134/13362865) it looks like you need to tell the Handler to encode things as UTF-8. This is done by passing `encoding='utf-8'` to the FileHandler() creation. I haven't tested this but it seems logical that it should work.

Comment: Sorry, I triedmodify the log. logging.FileHandler(rb"C:\Study\Other\Self-study\Code\newfile.log", 'w','utf-8') but it is not working