# Logging module leads to with locale on another machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, crash, locale

I am creating a larger python (v3.9) program which needs to run on a different, single core machine without any IDE or Python installed (both Win 10). For that use, I create an .exe file with PyInstaller:

```
pyinstaller main.py --name myProgram --clean --noconfirm --add-data="data;data" -i "data/Image.ico"
```

The code works on my main machine, but on the target machine the program crashes. After some debugging I found the crash to be at a logging step. I use logging to create a simple log, which works when the program is startet from the IDE or the .exe on my main machine, but fails at some point when the .exe is run on the target machine:

```
import logging

<code>

logging.basicConfig(filename='myProgram.log', format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S', level=logging.INFO)
logging.info("Program started.")

<more code>

print("A")                       # "A" is printed on both machines command lines
logging.info("some message")
print("B")                       # "B" is printed only on main machine, crash on target machine
```

What confuses me additionally is that I can't see any Error or Exception in the command line, even with something like this the program just stops:

```
try:
   logging.info("some message")
except Exception as e:
   print(e)
```

So far, I am at a loss at narrowing the error down further. What could lead to the correct logging of the first message and a crash on a logging attempt with the second message? I am thankful for any ideas for a solution or even for finding a better unterstanding of the problem itself.

Update: I found the reason for the crash, it was the use of the locale module, see my answer.

Comment: Is the target machine windows 7 or earlier?

Comment: Both machines are Win 10.

Answer (score 0):

Try computing an absolute path for the log filename and make sure the directory where the file should be exists and is writable by the created program.

Comment: I did just that: The program succesfully writes the file and logs the first entry, so it seems that the file is writebale. But the crash still occurs and the second entry still does not get logged.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. After putting a couple more logging statements in my code, I could narrow it down to another line between both logging statemens in the original post:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "de_DE")
```

After commenting that line, the program runs without crashes. I don't know why this happens, but this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64832140/python-crashing-when-using-logging-and-setting-locale-on-windows-10) had the same problem.

Comment: So not connected with logging? Perhaps the question title should be changed.